# Firebase favorite user list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database containing Users>userUID>Favorites and in this 'Favorite' node, i have the list of some posts that user save to your favorite, but i wanna to show a list in a RecyclerView containing only the posts saved, and the post are in another node Posts>... How can i do that, i mean, get only posts saved and search from another node to show in a RecyclerView??

That is the code tha i using to add to a favorite list of user

```
private void favoritos() {

    final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "Usuarios" );
    ref.child( mAuth.getUid() ).child( "Favoritos" ).child( posicao )
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals( posicao )) {
                            botaoFavorito.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_favoritos );
                            final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "Usuarios" );
                            ref.child( mAuth.getUid() ).child( "Favoritos" ).child( posicao ).setValue( null );
                        }
                    } else {
                        botaoFavorito.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_favorito_adicionado );
                        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "Usuarios" );
                        ref.child( mAuth.getUid() ).child( "Favoritos" ).child( posicao ).setValue( posicao );
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            } );
        }
```

And this is how my RecyclerView is showing data

```
recyclerView = findViewById( R.id.recyclerFavoritos );
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );

layoutDeCarregamento = new LinearLayoutManager( this );
layoutDeCarregamento.setReverseLayout( true );
layoutDeCarregamento.setStackFromEnd( true );

//Definindo o 'Layout'
recyclerView.setLayoutManager( layoutDeCarregamento );

firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

//Pegando os dados da tabela de referência
mRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference( "Usuarios" );
mRef.child( uid ).child( "Favoritos" );

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Noticias, dados_noticias> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Noticias, dados_noticias>(
                Noticias.class,
                R.layout.card_noticias,
                dados_noticias.class,
                mRef
        ) {
            @Override
            //Método para fazer o preenchimento dos dados na 'Recycler View'
            protected void populateViewHolder(dados_noticias viewHolder, Noticias noticias, int i) {

                viewHolder.setDetails( getBaseContext(), noticias.getTitulo(), noticias.getImagem_titulo(), noticias.getVisualizacoes(), noticias.getData(), noticias.getConteudo(), noticias.getPos() );

            }

            @Override
            public dados_noticias onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                final dados_noticias viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder( parent, viewType );
                viewHolder.setOnClickListener( new dados_noticias.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Ooops, erro aqui!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }
                } );
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };

//Mandando o adapter para o 'Recycler View'
recyclerView.setAdapter( firebaseRecyclerAdapter );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have done it before but in another way I hope it helps you:

Firstly, I did not save my favorites on Firebase, I worked on saving them on the cache memory in the form of **[GSON](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html)** for an important reason in my view, and there is no benefit every time he must open the application to download the favorite from Firebase, you do not measure it on only one user in the future

Second: I retrieved the saved data as List  and sent it to the Adapter

If you want to use this method, this is the code:

> **In Class Utils :**

```
public static List<String> getFavIDsList(Context context) {
        return Util.loadArrayFromPreference(context, Constant.FAV_ID_PREF);
    }


public static List<Product> getFavProductList(Context context) {

    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> gsonList = Util.loadArrayFromPreference(context, Constant.FAV_PRODUCT_PREF);

    for (String gson : gsonList)
        productList.add(new Gson().fromJson(gson, Product.class));

    return productList;
}



public static void updateProductListFav(Context context, Product product, boolean add) {

    //save for id list
    List<String> productIdList = getFavIDsList(context);
    if (add)
        productIdList.add(product.getId());
    else
        productIdList.remove(product.getId());

    Util.saveArrayToPreference(context, Constant.FAV_ID_PREF, productIdList);

    //save for object json list
    List<String> gsonProductList = Util.loadArrayFromPreference(context, Constant.FAV_PRODUCT_PREF);
    if (add)
        gsonProductList.add(new Gson().toJson(product));
    else{
        for(int i = 0 ; i< gsonProductList.size() ; i++){
            if(new Gson().fromJson(gsonProductList.get(i),Product.class).getId().equals(product.getId())){
                gsonProductList.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    Util.saveArrayToPreference(context, Constant.FAV_PRODUCT_PREF, gsonProductList);

}
```

> **FavoritesActivity**

```
productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(getContext());

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        binding.favoriteRv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        binding.favoriteRv.setAdapter(productAdapter);

        productAdapter.setProductList(ProductUtil.getFavProductList(getContext()));
```

> **In Adpater :**

```
public void setProductList(List<Product> productList) {

        this.productList = productList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**I hope** I helped you with this solution.

Comment: Wait ksksk You sayin' to save first in a GSON and then Firebase?? My node for user is **User>userID>Favorites> and here is all the posts saved**, and the node of post is **Posts> and here all posts**. The way that i think was get the all posts in node of user and then, relate in the posts node to show only the saved by user, but i don't know how to do this comparation . In fact, i'm a Civil Engeniring student that tryin' to make an app for  help us, my code level it's just the basic kskskksksk Do you know how to do the comaparation?? Thanks a lot!!!